# How to highlight Prolog code in Zerobrane Studio editor

Tags: zerobrane

I’m developing a Prolog interpreter which is callable from Lua.  I use ZBS as my IDE and I’d like to edit Prolog source files and see syntax highlighting, as works in Lua and XML and JSON…

I see in the ZBS (2.00) distribution that there is already a Prolog lexer defined, but looking at plug-in examples, I’m completely at a loss as to how to activate it for files with specific extensions (.pro and .pl)

Guidance much appreciated, I’m running under MacOS.

I’ve looked at my user configuration file to see where there might be a place to do this, but it’s not obvious to me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default configuration](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/src/config.lua#L119) only links the lexer to the .prolog extension, but you can add more by [setting a `specmap` value](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-editor-preferences#editor-extension-mapping) to whatever you need. In this case you can set `editor.specmap.pro = "prolog"` in `user.lua` to link `.pro` extension to the `prolog` lexer (and similar for `.pl`).

Comment: Oustanding!  That works a treat.  Now you linked the documentation I see it there.  I also read that _"Selecting a dialect is a simple matter of setting the
  buffer/lexer property "prolog.dialect" in init.lua"_, but, again, I'm unclear as to the exact call for this...

Comment: If you're using "iso", you don't need to do anything (as it's the default). You may need to call `editor:SetProperty("prolog.dialect", "gprolog")`, so create a simple plugin by adding this to user.lua: `package {
  onEditorNew =  function(self, ed) ed:SetProperty("prolog.dialect", "gprolog") end,
  onEditorLoad =  function(self, ed) ed:SetProperty("prolog.dialect", "gprolog") end,
}`